# C# WinForm multiple consecutive threaded web requests in a row

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, web-services

I have written a little tool in C# (WinForm) using Visual Studio 2012.

Its purpose is to let users check a given City and ZIP code against a database to validate if the city/zip combination is legit.

Everything works well so far (see the *simplyfied code* below). Since it is possible that users carry out more than one validation simultaneously, I've used a queue pattern (to make sure, I am sending the multiple requests in the right order, as they have been submitted).

Now, I need to modify my code to run 3 web requests to achive the same result.

Instead of just querying a webservice directly with city and zip code, I now need to make 3 requests in consecutive order:

1. send a code to a **webserver X** to request a key
2. send the obtained key to **webserver X** to validate city and zip code
3. send the validated result to **webserver Y** to save the city and zip code.

Obviously, I have to wait for the 1st request to be answered before I can proceed to carry out the 2nd request, and so on... And I need to check if the 2nd request returned true/valid otherwise I do not need to save/carry out the third request.

I need help on how to include these two more web requests in my code without breaking my queue mechanism. One item in my queue should now contain the 3 requests whilst making sure I am not requesting step 2 or 3 prior to step 1 or step 2 having delivered a (valid) result.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CheckAddress.Util;

namespace CheckAddress.Api
{
    public class ApiHelper
    {
        #region singleton
        private static ApiHelper _instance;
        private static Object _lock = new object();

        public static ApiHelper Instance
        {
            get
            {
                lock (_lock)
                {
                    if (_instance == null)
                    {
                        _instance = new ApiHelper();
                    }
                }
                return _instance;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        private Thread _queueThread;
        private bool _running;
        private Queue<Address> _queue;

        private ApiHelper()
        {
            _running = false;
            _queue = new Queue<Address>();

            MaxThreads = SettingsFile.Instance.MaxThreads;
            MaxAttempts = SettingsFile.Instance.MaxAttempts;

            ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(MaxThreads, MaxThreads);
        }

        public int MaxThreads { get; set; }
        public int MaxAttempts { get; set; }

        public void Add(Address a)
        {
            lock (_queue)
            {
                _queue.Enqueue(a);
            }
        }

        private void AddressSendProc(object state)
        {
            bool isValid = false;

            foreach (Address.CityZIP theCityZIP in a.listOfAddresses)
            {
                while (!success && tries < MaxAttempts)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://domain.com/geo.php?city=auburn&zip=95602");
                        req.Method = "GET";

                        req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:2.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
                        req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
                        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

                        req.Timeout = 3000;
                        var resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

                        var ms = new MemoryStream();
                        var rs = resp.GetResponseStream();
                        if (rs != null)
                        {
                            var buf = new byte[4096];
                            int len = 0;
                            while ((len = rs.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length)) > 0)
                            {
                                ms.Write(buf, 0, len);
                            }
                            rs.Close();
                        }

                        var xml = new XmlDocument();
                        xml.LoadXml(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()));
                        var nodes = xml.SelectNodes("/response/valid");
                        if (nodes.Count == 1)
                        {
                            isValid = true;
                        }
                        int code = 0;
                        Int32.TryParse(nodes[0].InnerText, out code);

                        if (code == 200)
                        {
                            success = true;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        /* */
                    }
                    tries++;
                }
            }
        }

        private void ApiThreadProc()
        {
            while (_running)
            {
                try
                {
                    lock (_queue)
                    {
                        while (_queue.Count > 0)
                        {
                            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressSendProc, _queue.Dequeue());
                        }
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
                catch (Exception) {/*ignore*/}
            }
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            _running = true;
            _queueThread = new Thread(ApiThreadProc);
            _queueThread.Start();
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            _running = false;
            if (_queueThread != null)
            {
                _queueThread.Interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since the web requests are synchronous and ordered, just code them into a single function.  No need to queue each request.  If you MUST queue each request then make a class to hold all three and queue that.

Comment: @Dan-o thank you for your fast reply! How would I code to wait for the WebRequest to finish (with either success or failure result)? Can I simply cascade the 3 requests?